# Instead of 2nd author, corresponding indication is showing wrongly for the 1st author in bmcart.cls

Tags: pdftex, author, affiliation

If I have only one address and author count is 2, and the 2 second is the corresponding author that time corresponding indication is showing wrongly for the 1st author 
[bmcart.cls](https://github.com/HongjianLi/tex/blob/master/BMC/bmcart.cls)

```
    \documentclass{bmcart}
    \def\includegraphic{}
    \def\includegraphics{}
    \startlocaldefs
    \endlocaldefs


    \begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
    \begin{fmbox}
    \dochead{Research}


    \title{A sample article title}


    \author[
       addressref={aff1},                   % id's of addresses, e.g. {aff1,aff2}
       noteref={n1},                        % id's of article notes, if any
       email={sample@saple.com}   % email address
    ]{\inits{JE}\fnm{Jane E} \snm{Doe}}
    \author[
       addressref={aff1},
       corref={aff1},                       % id of corresponding address, if any
       email={sample1@saple.com}
    ]{\inits{JRS}\fnm{John RS} \snm{Smith}}


    \address[id=aff1]{%                           % unique id
      \orgname{Department of Zoology, Cambridge}, % university, etc
      \street{Waterloo Road},                     %
      %\postcode{}                                % post or zip code
      \city{London},                              % city
      \cny{UK}                                    % country
    }
    \begin{artnotes}
    \note[id=n1]{Equal contributor} 
    \end{artnotes}

    \end{fmbox}

    \begin{abstractbox}

    \begin{abstract} % abstract
    \parttitle{First part title} %if any
    Text for this section.

    \parttitle{Second part title} %if any
    Text for this section.
    \end{abstract}


    \begin{keyword}
    \kwd{sample}
    \kwd{article}
    \kwd{author}
    \end{keyword}



    \end{abstractbox}
    %
    %\end{fmbox}% uncomment this for twcolumn layout

    \end{frontmatter}

    \begin{backmatter}

    \section*{Competing interests}
      The authors declare that they have no competing interests.

    \section*{Author's contributions}
        Text for this section \ldots

    \section*{Acknowledgements}
      Text for this section \ldots
    \bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys}
    \bibliography{bmc_article}      
    \end{backmatter}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in the BMC template. The bug doesn't seem to occur however when you do not provide an email address for the first author, I'm not sure if the email address is required somewhere else but otherwise that may be a workaround. I noticed that you have already added an issue on Github, maybe it would be useful to add your MWE to that issue as well? Note that you don't need the bibliography part or the `def`s and `localdefs` part, which look a bit strange anyway.